# Asp.NET Core Razor Error On Debian Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am developing a asp.net core app.
I was added a simple view and action.
action has a line of code "return View();".
It was successfuly running on my pc (windows, visual studio 2017) when i try access view no problem.
But i deploy app to my debian server and i try access view it has a exception.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
>   xe1uuj0w.g4y(18,67): error CS0508: '_Views_Admin_Index_cshtml.ExecuteAsync()': return type must be 'Task' to match overridden member 'RazorPageBase.ExecuteAsync()'
>   xe1uuj0w.g4y(18,67): error CS7069: Reference to type 'Task' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument, String generatedCode)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(String relativePath)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CreateCacheEntry(String normalizedPath)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Comment: Some more information is needed:

Which version of .NET Core on Windows are you using?

Which version of .NET Core on Debian are you using?

Have you tried Googling the error message, particularly the `return type must be 'Task' to match overridden member 'RazorPageBase.ExecuteAsync()` part? (It matches a bug report on GitHub)

Comment: Yes i was googled. Windows version:2.0.0, Debian version:2.0.2